# Mail server connection failed - while trying to send the email through SMTP

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to sending the mail through smtp, but it shows the error message.
i am using host number is 578.after execution of the program it shows the 
Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

```
EmailController.java

package com.jcg.spring.mvc.email;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class EmailController {

    static String emailToRecipient, emailSubject, emailMessage;
    static final String emailFromRecipient = "srinivasaraojella@gmail.com";

    static ModelAndView modelViewObj;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSenderObj;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "emailForm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showEmailForm(ModelMap model) {
        modelViewObj = new ModelAndView("emailForm");
        return  modelViewObj;       
    }

    // This Method Is Used To Prepare The Email Message And Send It To The Client
    @RequestMapping(value = "sendEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sendEmailToClient(HttpServletRequest request, final @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFileObj) {

        // Reading Email Form Input Parameters      
        emailSubject = request.getParameter("subject");
        emailMessage = request.getParameter("message");
        emailToRecipient = request.getParameter("mailTo");

        // Logging The Email Form Parameters For Debugging Purpose
        System.out.println("\nReceipient?= " + emailToRecipient + ", Subject?= " + emailSubject + ", Message?= " + emailMessage + "\n");

        mailSenderObj.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                MimeMessageHelper mimeMsgHelperObj = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");             
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setTo(emailToRecipient);
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setFrom(emailFromRecipient);               
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setText(emailMessage);
                mimeMsgHelperObj.setSubject(emailSubject);

                // Determine If There Is An File Upload. If Yes, Attach It To The Client Email              
                if ((attachFileObj != null) && (attachFileObj.getSize() > 0) && (!attachFileObj.equals(""))) {
                    System.out.println("\nAttachment Name?= " + attachFileObj.getOriginalFilename() + "\n");
                    mimeMsgHelperObj.addAttachment(attachFileObj.getOriginalFilename(), new InputStreamSource() {                   
                        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                            return attachFileObj.getInputStream();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nNo Attachment Is Selected By The User. Sending Text Email!\n");
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nMessage Send Successfully.... Hurrey!\n");

        modelViewObj = new ModelAndView("success","messageObj","Thank You! Your Email Has Been Sent!");
        return  modelViewObj;   
    }
}


spring-servlet.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.jcg.spring.mvc.email" />

        <!-- Spring Email Sender Bean Configuration -->
        <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
            <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
            <property name="port" value="587" />
            <property name="username" value="srinivasaraojella@gmail.com" />
            <property name="password" value="srinu877$@" />
            <property name="javaMailProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- Spring Email Attachment Configuration -->
        <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
            <!-- Maximum Upload Size In Bytes -->
            <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
            <!-- Maximum Size Of File In Memory (In Bytes) -->
            <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Resolves Views Selected For Rendering by @Controllers to *.jsp Resources in the /WEB-INF/ Folder -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Send Email Exception Resolver i.e. In Case Of Exception The Controller Will Navigate To 'error.jsp' & Will Display The Exception Message -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
            <property name="exceptionMappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean> 
    </beans>
```

error like this:Sorry, The Email Was Not Sent Because Of The Following Error! Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so ugly, use service class for implementation. Don't do that in controller. 
And your send email method is pretty weird. Do it in this way:

```
private void send(String to, String from, String message, String subject, String attachmentName, InputStreamSource inputStreamSource) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mail = mailSenderObj.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
    if (subject == null) {
        subject = "";
    }
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setFrom(from);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText(message, true);
    helper.addAttachment(attachmentName, inputStreamSource);
    mailSenderObj.send(mail);
}
```

And try to change your XML to that:

```
         <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>                    
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

I think you don't need to set socket. 
Atleast in my spring boot application (when I use application.properties instead XML) i don't need to set that.